# Is it possible to get an input from a cmd command line?

Tags: python

```
python program1.py
```

This is what i input when i try  to open my file using cmd.

```
python program1.py C:\Logs
```

Is it possible to have an input like the one above so i can use that input on my program ? The input should be on the same command calling the python code

Comment: `sys.argv` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, If you're asking how to give args I'm pretty sure it's python program.py "Arg". If you asking how to get it, import sys, and it is stored in sys.argv